# Check if a particular JSON Object is available or not

Tags: java, android, json, object

I have JSON File as below which has to be dumped into an ArrayList:

```
{
 "main1" : [
  {
     "child1" : valueA,
     "child2" : valueB,
     "child3" : valueC,
  },
  {
     "child1" : value1,
     "child3" : value3,
  },
 ],
 "main2" : "valueMain2"
}
```

The element `child2` has to be checked if it exists or not and then the value is taken. You can see that it doesn't appear in the second array.

I am using Native JSON (org.JSON)
Java Code is below:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> myList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
JSONObject json = <my_json_object>;

JSONObject getchild2;

JSONArray jArray = <my_json_object>.getJSONArray("main1");
for(int j = 0; j < jArray.length(), j++){
  HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();

  map.put("First Value", jArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("child1"));
  map.put("Third Value", jArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("child3"));

  getchild2 = jArray.getJSONObject(j).getJSONObject("child2");
  if(getchild2 == null){
    map.put("Second Value", "Some Dummy Value");
  } else {
    map.put("Second Value", jArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("child2"));
  }
 myList.add(map);
}
```

How can I achieve this?

`<my_json_object>` uses native URL Parsing as I get the HTTP Response of a URL request found here: http://mobisys.in/blog/2012/01/parsing-json-from-url-in-android/

It doesn't work as error is below:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(664): Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
```

Comment: Please paste your code and error if you get any

Comment: Can you please paste the java code,how you are converting json to json object?

Comment: Code Added!! Please check and let me know.

Comment: where exactly is the error shown? in which line?

Comment: This happens when the JSON Object "child2" is to be checked.

Comment: why you are using jArray.getJSONObject(j).getJSONObject("child2"); why not jArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("child2") ??

Comment: I solved it myself. Refer to the question again.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Anyway, I got the solution with some Googling:
I re-framed it as,

```
 if (!jArray.getJSONObject(j).has("child2")) {
  map.put("Second Value", "N.A");
 } else {
  map.put("Second Value", jArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("child2"));
 }
```

Creating the JSONObject getchild2 = jArray.getJSONObject(j).getJSONObject("child2"); was rather, unnecessary.

And this works, rather perfectly! Refer this for more details: [Checking if exists subObject in JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10063866/checking-if-exists-subobject-in-json)

Thanks everyone for the help!

Comment: i want to check for any json object perticular value exist or not ?

like here {"ValidateUserResult":[{"Sys_User_ID":69,"my_id":23}]}

i want to check in response "my_id" string is available or not?

any one have idea about it?

Comment: Extend the same thing as I gave the solution. Should be fine enough.

Comment: I have the following JSON file: http://pagesbyz.com/test.json and I am running into the same issue. Here is my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19868439/how-to-put-json-information-in-an-array-to-use-it-for-displaying-in-listview (If there is a blank entry, the JSON file is not parsed anymore :/) I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 11):

```
getJSONObject("child2");
```

Will throw an exception if child2 does not exist. Try this instead:

```
getchild2 = jArray.getJSONObject(j).optJSONObject("child2");
```

That way you don't have to catch an exception if child2 doesn't exist and can instead check for null.

Comment: But I have problems. How to get the value `valueB` if the object exists? I tried using the same code. Wasn't able to get it.

Comment: Now I reframed it,

`    JSONObject getchild2 = jArray.getJSONObject(j).optJSONObject("child2");
     if (getchild2 == null) {
       map.put("rating", "N.A");
     } else {
       map.put("rating", jArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("child2"));
     }`

The fact is, the result should return a value, but is not returning. Always points to "N.A" as the result. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
{"main1" : [{
             "id":"1"
               "child1" : "valueA",
               "child2" : "valueB",
               "child3" : "valueC",
            }, {
                "id":"2"
                  "child1" : "value1",
                 "child3"  : "value3",
           }]
}
```