# How to put JSON information in an array to use it for displaying in ListView

Tags: java, android, json, android-fragments

I have an Activity which has three fragments and I am trying to retrieve a JSON file from my server which I will be updating on a daily basis.

My JSON file is located here: **http://pagesbyz.com/test.json**

Because there are fragments, I used the following code in my `MainActivity` class:

```
DefaultHttpClient   httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://pagesbyz.com/test.json");
        // Depends on your web service
        httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        InputStream inputStream = null;
        String result = null;
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);           
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            inputStream = entity.getContent();
            // json is UTF-8 by default
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            result = sb.toString();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, 2000).show();
        } catch (Exception e) { 
            // Oops
        }
        finally {
            try{if(inputStream != null)inputStream.close();}catch(Exception squish){}
        }
```

What I really need to do is retrieve the `TYPE` field in my JSON file and separate it into three tabs and put it inside a `ListView` like this:

[image]

I would like to know once I have read the JSON file by using the code on top how do I proceed... Thanks for the help :)

Should I query on each fragment and then look for the TYPE field? Would that be easier?

Curious as to why the Toast did not execute... Here is the pastebin for my main activity: http://pastebin.com/gKTCeH79

Comment: Use a JSON (de-)serializing framework such as [org.json](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html), [gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) or [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson). Also I strongly advise against performing network operations on the UI thread, which you seem to be doing.

Comment: Thanks. Which is easier to use and is there a documentation that I can use?

Comment: You're welcome. org.json is accessible in Android without any external dependency. Jackson is my personal favorite for simplicity and performance but it's a bit subjective. All frameworks are well documented.

Comment: I am also wondering why the Toast did not execute?

Comment: @SiKn8 at first sight it's probably because an `Exception` was thrown before the `Toast` was called. Since your `catch` statement does nothing, the outcome would be whatever happens in the `finally` statement.

Comment: Consider [logging](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) in your exceptions.

Comment: `11-08 16:18:53.023: I/TEST(5799): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` You are right :) How would I resolve it?

Comment: Use an `AsyncTask` for the network operations. It's a bit of a simplistic answer but will work in your case.

Comment: Ok... I used AsyncTask before and I just reused and I finally got the whole thing to work :)! Now to extract them and do the next step. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is use Androids JSONObject and JSONArray to access your json data.

For example since your root is a json array you want to instantiate a JSONArray object from your json data you have.

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);
```

Now from this array you can grab individual JSONObject for each object in your array.

```
JSONObject objectOne = new JSONObject(0); // Grabs your first item
```

From the JSONObject you can now access your three values.

```
String type = objectOne.get("type") // Will give you the value for type
```

JSONArray:  http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html

JSONObject: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html

Another way is to use a framework that lets you deserialize json into Java POJO's (Plain Old Java Objects). Gson is the easiest to use.

The basic idea is you make an object that relates directly to your json objects, after you have this you can easily store your data in java objects and use it however you like.

GSON example:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
MyCustomClass obj2 = gson.fromJson(json, MyCustomClass.class);
```

Where MyCustomClass would contain the variables id, type, and data.

GSON reference: https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide

Good Luck!

Comment: `jsonString` is which variable in my class?

Comment: This would be the result you get back from your network call. Also all networking needs to be done on a separate thread and not the UI thread. I would recommend using Androids AsyncTask to run your network call on a new thread. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: I was able to receive the json text and now to extract it. I am thinking I can put it in a Public array which can be accessible by any of the fragments within the activity.

Comment: Yeah that would be one approach to do it, if you are looking to expand on this and maybe persist the data you may want to look into storing your data in a database on the phone once you receive it. This way where ever you are in your app you could do a query to retrieve the data. But like I said, this may be more than what you need for your application.

Comment: What if some of the entry is NO DATA, can I dummy fill it with data?

Comment: Do you mean that your value is just an empty string after parsing the JSON?

Comment: Like one of the JSON array entry won't have the `data` label or any values there. Eclipse gives me a warning: `11-11 15:26:11.433: W/System.err(9054): org.json.JSONException: No value for data`
I am wondering if the any of the label is missing, just fill it with dummy data.

Comment: You can use the isNull method available in the JSONObject to check if there is data there. jsonObject.isNull("data"); This will return true if there is no mapping for data. So you can only try to grab a value for data if that returns false.

Comment: Is there anyway to fill it with dummy, or it just won't be allowed to do that?

Comment: If you look at my full program code, maybe you will have a better understanding of it?

Comment: You can add a property to a json object by doing something like this: jsonObject.put("data", "some value"); And you could do this after checking the isNull I mentioned before. Does that help?

Comment: I have 7 entries but once it received a blank entry it skips everything after. Here is my Pastebin: http://pastebin.com/260jvLcx (I am opening up a chat for this)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40980/discussion-between-sikni8-and-dejanristic)