# How to print a string if data is not available on server in android using json

Tags: android, json

Thank you guys.Finally i got the solution.If we want to check whether string is empty or null we must trim() the string.

```
      String url="http://app name/Api/GetJobDetails/GetJobDetails?COMP_REQ_ID=" + title + "&StuEmail=" + e ;  // this is the url
      AQuery mAQuery = new AQuery(SecondActivity.this);
      mAQuery.ajax(url, String.class, new AjaxCallback<String>() {
      public Object dataSource;
      @Override
      public void callback(String url, String data, AjaxStatus status)
      {
      uper.callback(url, data, status);
      if (null != data && status.getCode() != -101) {
      String StringData = "" + data;
      try {
              JSONArray rootArray = new JSONArray(StringData);
              int len = rootArray.length();
              for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
              JSONObject json = rootArray.optJSONObject(i);
              String Salary = json.optString("Req_From_Sal");
              if (Salary == null || Salary.trim().equals("null") ||   Salary.trim().length() <= 0) {
              b14.setText("Not Mentioned");
              }
              else
              {
              b14.setText(""+Salary);
              }

        }
      } 
    }
});
```

Comment: if (Salary == null||Salary.equals("null"))

Comment: I don't know exactly where you want to check but yes this is wrong  if `(Salary == null)`. Instead of use `if(TextUtils.isEmpty(Salary))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if a particular JSON Object is available or not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10594188/check-if-a-particular-json-object-is-available-or-not)

Comment: i am not stroring the JSON values locally

Comment: `String salary = json.optString("Req_From_Sal"); \
if(!salary.isEmpty()){  
b14.setText(""+Salary);
 }else{
//Show Error message
}`

Comment: i want to print  a string " salary is not mentioned" in else part.how can i do this .please help me

Answer (score 0):

Check you string if it is null or blank then print message what you want. For example:

```
if(StringData.length()==0){
//show message
}else{
 JSONArray rootArray = new JSONArray(StringData);

          int len = rootArray.length();
          for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
          JSONObject json = rootArray.optJSONObject(i);
          String Salary = json.optString("Req_From_Sal");
          if (Salary == null)
          b14.setText("NA"+Salary);
          else
          b14.setText(""+Salary)
          }
}
```

MoreOver if you want to show specific message for specific user then ask for the **success** parameter. `If success==1` go for you logic else if `success ==0` then ask for **message** parameter as well parse it and show it to user

Comment: how to print a message in if block

Comment: You can go for creating an interface that you can implement or if you are directly using this function in activity simply take a tectview and set any text message on it that you want to show

Comment: I got the solution by using trim() method

Comment: trim() method removes white spaces from string

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys.Finally i got the solution. Here is edit code.To check the String is null or  empty we should have to trim() the string.

**Android side:-**

```
String url="http://app name/Api/GetJobDetails/GetJobDetails?COMP_REQ_ID=" + title + "&StuEmail=" + e ;  // this is the url


                AQuery mAQuery = new AQuery(SecondActivity.this);
                mAQuery.ajax(url, String.class, new AjaxCallback<String>() {

                public Object dataSource;

                 @Override

                 public void callback(String url, String data, AjaxStatus status) {

                 uper.callback(url, data, status);

                 if (null != data && status.getCode() != -101) {

                 String StringData = "" + data;
                 try {
                 JSONArray rootArray = new JSONArray(StringData);
                 int len = rootArray.length();
                 for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
                 JSONObject json = rootArray.optJSONObject(i);

                 String Job_Title = json.optString("Req_Title");
                 String Designation = json.optString("Req_Designation_Role");
                 String Job_Type = json.optString("Req_Job_Type");
                String Salary = json.optString("Req_From_Sal");


                 if(Job_Title == null || Job_Title .trim().equals("null") ||Job_Title .trim().length<=0){
                   b1.setText("Job title not set.");
                }else{
                   b1.setText("" +Job_Title); 
                }

                if(Designation == null || Designation.trim().equals("null") ||Designation.trim().length() <= 0){
                   b3.setText("Job Designation not set.");
                }else{
                   b3.setText("" +Designation); 
                }

                 if(Job_Type == null || Job_Type.trim().equals("null") || Job_Type.trim().length() <= 0){
                   b13.setText("Job Type not set.");
                }else{
                  b13.setText("" +Job_Type);
                }

                 if(Salary == null || Salary.trim().equals("null") || Salary.trim().length() <= 0){
                   b14.setText("Not yet Mentioned");
                }else{
                  b14.setText(""+Salary);
                }

            }
          } 
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please explain  the procedure how to do

Comment: Okay @AnushaDandu. Even you can try to understand my above explain which I have written. Anyway I will explain you in detail.

Comment: How to get response from the server

Comment: Would please tell me, are you using Volley to do request from server or HttpClient class of java? Are you doing api resquest(Web-services) or have stored json locally? It will be easy for me to elaborate you.

Comment: I am using web API for the services.  I am  retrieving data if it is available.If data is not available for  an item in array  i just want to print a string.

Comment: Okay nice. I going to edit my answer in more clear way.

Comment: i am using web services (API) and retrieving the data through JSON.Please help me Rana

Comment: Rana  i will edit my  code what i have done. U can elaborate me in little bit more.

Comment: Thank you for spending time Rana. But the b14 is showing blank.It is not displaying string.Please tell me how to figure it

Comment: Ha. i have seen updated code and tried. But b14 is showing blank.It is not displaying string("Salary type not displayed")

Comment: Whatever changes you  made, i have tried.now data is not retrieving from server even though there is data in server.

Comment: Can you send me a single value of COMP_REQ_ID,StuEmail. Because I want to test your api response.

Comment: i am retrieving COMP_REQ_ID from data base using service.

Comment: Yes I am getting it. I need a demo email or id for testing. With that I can request api.

Comment: I can give the mail id ,But i cannot reveal the original request  API in public because it is confidential

Comment: Can you give me on my email. No need to send me any original id. Just give a demo credentials

Comment: i have sent mail to you please check it once.

Comment: i sent company id and student email check it once

Comment: Thank you Rana .I got finally by using trim() method

Answer (score 0):

1.Check whether `StringData` is null or empty.

2.Check if `rootArray.length()==0`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
    if(StringData!=null) {
        JSONArray rootArray = new JSONArray(StringData);
        for (int i = 0; i < rootArray.length(); ++i) {
            JSONObject json = rootArray.optJSONObject(i);
            String Job_Title = json.optString("Req_Title", "default_value");
            String Designation = json.optString("Req_Designation_Role", "default_value");
            String Salary = json.optString("Req_From_Sal", "Salary Not Mentioned");
            b14.setText("" + Salary);
        }
    }else{
        Log.d(TAG, "Invalid JSON Data");
        b14.setText("Salary Not Mentioned");
    }
```

Comment: I tried but it was not working.for example if data is available it is displaying b14=15000,in the case of no salary it was displaying simply b14. But i have to print a string like "not mentioned" if there is no data.

Comment: Try updated code and ask me if you have any problem without any hesitation.

Comment: Desai i have edited the code .Please help me how to print a string if data is not available in server

Comment: i tried desai please figure out me from this problem

Comment: i didn't get any error.i just want to print a string if data is not available from server

Answer (score 0):

USe TextUtils.isEmpty() to check for null and empty string.
Always add null check before getting any variable from object.

Modified code below:

```
JSONArray rootArray = new JSONArray(StringData);
if(rootArray!=null&&rootArray.length())

{
    int len = rootArray.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)

    {
        JSONObject json = rootArray.optJSONObject(i);
        if (json != null) {

            String Job_Title = json.optString("Req_Title");
            String Designation = json.optString("Req_Designation_Role");
            String Job_Type = json.optString("Req_Job_Type");
            String Salary;
            if (json.has("Req_From_Sal") && !TextUtils.isEmpty(json.getString("Req_From_Sal")) {
                Salary = json.optString("Req_From_Sal");
            } else {
                Salary = "Not available";
            }
            b14.setText(Salary);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: its not if (json.has("Req_From_Sal") && !TextUtils.isEmpty(json.getString("Req_From_Sal") != null))Please check I have updated the code.