# Want to get php data to android

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, json

My LogCat errors are:

```
    12-31 10:42:42.534: W/dalvikvm(292): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
12-31 10:42:42.544: E/AndroidRuntime(292): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
12-31 10:42:42.764: E/AndroidRuntime(292): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-31 10:42:42.764: E/AndroidRuntime(292):  at com.example.visit.record.My_Task$GetTaskDetails.onPostExecute(My_Task.java:204)
12-31 10:42:42.764: E/AndroidRuntime(292):  at com.example.visit.record.My_Task$GetTaskDetails.onPostExecute(My_Task.java:1)
12-31 10:42:42.764: E/AndroidRuntime(292):  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
12-31 10:42:42.764: E/AndroidRuntime(292):  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
12-31 10:42:42.764: E/AndroidRuntime(292):  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
12-31 10:42:42.764: E/AndroidRuntime(292):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-31 10:42:42.764: E/AndroidRuntime(292):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-31 10:42:42.764: E/AndroidRuntime(292):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
12-31 10:42:42.764: E/AndroidRuntime(292):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-31 10:42:42.764: E/AndroidRuntime(292):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-31 10:42:42.764: E/AndroidRuntime(292):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
12-31 10:42:42.764: E/AndroidRuntime(292):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
12-31 10:42:42.764: E/AndroidRuntime(292):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-31 10:42:42.784: I/dalvikvm(292): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
12-31 10:42:42.784: E/dalvikvm(292): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied
12-31 10:42:46.564: I/Process(292): Sending signal. PID: 292 SIG: 9
12-31 10:42:47.574: D/dalvikvm(315): GC freed 604 objects / 50648 bytes in 108ms
```

In my application, I am trying to get data from Mysql database using JSON on php. I code it to get customer name, contact no, ticket no and task details in android using JSONParser. but unluckly not getting appropriate results:( can anyone tell me that where i go wrong and why it not work to get data from database? Does i use any other request in php? kindly review my php code too. I'll be very thankful to you if you point out my error and guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here

```
if(method == "POST")
```

you are using `==` for comparing String Contain which is not valid because `==` is used for Comparing object reference if you want to compare contain value then using String.equals as:

```
if(method.equals( "POST"))
```

or using `equalsIgnoreCase`

```
if(method.equalsIgnoreCase( "POST"))
```

Comment: ok, kindly review my logcat, i can't understand how to resolve these errors

Comment: @Android : now your error move from doInBackground to onPostExecute what is line number My_Task.java:204?

Comment: a/c to Logcat it display error on   "  cus_name_txtbx.setText(my_task.getString(TAG_NAME));  "

Comment: line no 204 is:  cus_name_txtbx.setText(my_task.getString(TAG_NAME));  whats wrong in it??

Comment: @Android : NullPointerException means you are not getting value from JSON just try after setting static values in onPostExecute

Comment: @ ρяσѕρєя K: so how can i resolve it?? i set static on JSON object. what can i do to resolve it??? thanks for your response

Comment: @Android : i'm saying first identify problem  either in json parsing or some other place .for this set  cus_name_txtbx.setText("test"); and same for rest of UI fields and check app is running or not

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21932/discussion-between--k-and-android)

Comment: @Android : make sure you are getting json from server if yes plz post it with question then we will see you are doing parsing in right way or not

Comment: How can i know that getting json from server?

Comment: @Android : just print this  json = sb.toString(); as `Log.v("json from server ::",json);`

Comment: 12-31 12:05:17.094: V/json from server ::(593): {"success":0,"message":"No task found"}
12-31 12:05:17.094: D/Single Task Details(593): {"message":"No task found","success":0}
@ρяσѕρєя K: yes it is connected with server because it display my php code of json where i used if condition that "success= 0, no task found". now what can i do?

Comment: @ ρяσѕρєя K: Sorry, actually i want to post it in another question. now i again post it. kindly see the edited question

Comment: @Android : k post new question and you will need to check for key it is exist in current json string to not before parsing it like in current code cus_name not exist in json return from server . see this post for more help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10063866/checking-if-exists-subobject-in-json